# div Height is not 100% in next.js

Tags: html, css, next.js

I have a problem to stylize pages in next.js. I want to have full height pages.

Therefore, I set the height attribute in body and html tags, it is OK and I have full height for body and html tags(proved in dev tools) but although I set #__next height to 100%, I could not achieve full height for it.
If I apply other measurements like px or vh, it is affected.

layout.css

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: @text-font-family;
  direction: rtl !important;
  text-align: start !important;
}
#__next {
height: 100%; // or min-height
}
```

[image: HTML DOM]

Comment: the body need to have height defined, not min-height

Comment: Temani Afif ,thanks, with % we need height as well,yes.

Comment: If you only need to make sure that a `div` has at least the size of the viewport, you can make the `div` css with `min-heigth: 100vh;`. There's no need to change the css of the `html`, `body` and `#__next` elements.

Comment: 100vh is not without problems though, hence the introduction of lvh & svh units https://dev.to/frehner/css-vh-dvh-lvh-svh-and-vw-units-27k4

Comment: I fixed by commenting out tailwinds in globals.css, otherwise all divs height was 0
/* @tailwind base;@tailwind components;@tailwind utilities; */

Answer (score 20):

`position: absolute;` might work for you

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#__next {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="__next"></div>
```

Or just ensure that `html`, `body` and `#__next` all have `height: 100%`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}



#__next {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="__next"></div>
```